# Why is Apache cordova's cordova-plus-admob plugin not working?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-admob

I am using cordova-plus-admob plugin in my apache cordova app, but the plugin is not showing ads. Also, there is no error in the console. I am trying to start Admobu but it is not giving any response.I did all the admob installations.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", () => {
  admob.start().then(() => {
    console.log("ADMOB STARTED");
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. admob.start or trying to load an app is never finished and I also do not receive any errors. I am wondering if admob is still checking my apps in my account even though the review process is already done since over 7 days now. Have you made any progress?

Comment: I made it work with the forked community admob plugin: https://github.com/admob-plus/admob-plus/issues/574

Comment: No unfortunately. You can replace it with cordova-plugin-firebase-admob
I decided to use the plugin.